# event handler not binding

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code is here:

The event handler is supposed to make it so that when the user clicks a button, there is an alert and a prompt that asks for a number, then the program generates a grid with a number of boxes according to the number the user provided. Unfortunately, though, the event handler is not binding and the code within it is not working.
We are at odds why.

Thanks for taking a look.

EDIT 
SORRY
http://codepen.io/pauldd91/pen/zxAhs

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or something ? There is no code here.

Comment: The code is here: *no code*....?

Comment: CODE CODE CODE CODE CODE

Comment: I think they want code.

Comment: We're all addicted and need our code fix!

Comment: ok i added the code. you are all great.

Comment: Did you check for JS errors in the console?  Because I see one, which would explain why consequent JS execution is not working...

Comment: @Steve you're right, thanks, that got the prompts showing up. Unfortunately, it's still not producing the new grids though.

Comment: blind without code!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem as mentioned above is the use of `block` when you mean `blocks`. Also the reason they are not reshowing is because you are using `$('#square_holder').detach();` This removes it from the dom and then you cannot re append items. Just clear it using `$('#square_holder').html("");` or `$('#square_holder').empty();`and it will work.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iynsp

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, I see the following error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: block is not defined

It is caused by the following line:

```
var dimension = ((960/block) - (blocks * 2));
```

Since you never declared `block`, JS throws an error and any further JS execution is stopped.  Once you assign a value for `block` (or change it to a value), your handler works fine.

Comment: thanks. I fixed that, but the new grids aren't generated from the user input still. thanks though